# sailjs search in many to many

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

have 2 models with many to many assoc(MongoDB). How I can find in assoc. EXAMPLE
USER MODEL

```
name: {
type:'string'
},
groups:{
collection:'Group'
via:'users'
}
```

GROUP MODEL

```
name:{
type:'string'
},
users:{
collection:'User',
via:'groups'
}
```

how I can find all users in all Groups when name=Jack ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Group.find().populate('users', {
    name: 'Jack'
}).exec(function(err, groups) {
    // ...
});
```

**UPD:** As I understand from your comment you only want groups with Jack-users. So you can just do something like:

```
User.find({
    name: 'Jack'
}).populate('groups').exec(function(err, users) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: this find ALL groups, but do populate fields only where user name = Jack

Comment: @Eugene Updated answer. If I catch your problem correctly this might help you.

Comment: How I can find in current group only users where name jack? like this (blueprint) GET group/:id/users?where={"name":"Jack"} but  this not work, only Limit work